# Salto de linea entre label e input type

Tags: css, formularios, cakephp-3.x

EN CakePHP 3.6 ¿Como hago un salto de linea entre el label y el input type?

```
  <?= $this->Form->control('nombre', ['placeholder' => 'Nombre', 'class' => 'nombre', 'size' => '20', 'maxlength' => '30']); ?>
```

Me muestra el label y el input en una sola linea, pero yo lo quiero mostrar en lineas separadas.

Comment: Por qué no concatenas una etiqueta <br> entre el label y el input?

Comment: ¿Como hago esa concatenación? algo como esto: `'nombre<br>', [` lo había pensado pero no se si se puede.

Comment: Puedes decirme como lo muestra en el navegador?, puedo ayudarte con CSS para que se muestre como quieres :)

Comment: Así lo muestra --> '<div class="input text required"><label for="nombre">Nombre</label><input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="nombre-add" size="20" maxlength="30" required="required" id="nombre"/></div>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te sirve una solución con CSS, puedes probar algo asi:

```
.input label[for] {
  display: block;
}
```

Al hacer el label un elemento bloque, ocupará todo el ancho disponible.

Comment: Perdona la tardanza, voy a dar tu respuesta por valida porque es lo que quería pero con una pequeña corrección 'label[for] {
  display: block;
}`  Saludos.